# Using Mailgun RestFUL's on client-side

Tags: javascript, api, email, rest, mailgun

I am attempting to build an anonymous customer feedback form which forwards the content to an email address. I've been looking into Mailgun (http://documentation.mailgun.com/api-sending.html), but I am confused where I could put in my API key. I am attempting to make a POST request with jQuery, could someone point me to an example of sending an email?

Answer (score 2):

According to [the Authentication section of Mailgun's API Intro](http://documentation.mailgun.com/api-intro.html#authentication), they require Basic Auth, which is accomplished in code by adding the following HTTP header:

```
Authorization: Basic base64($username:$password)
```

For Mailgun, they mention using `api` as the username and your API key as the password.

For more details on how to add the Basic Auth header via jQuery, see this:
[How to use Basic Auth with jQuery and AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507234/how-to-use-basic-auth-and-jquery-and-ajax)